# how to send push from app

Tags: ios6, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am making real estate app where I want to send push when any building is added. What I tried is as per below link.

[Urban Airship - Send Push with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592762/urban-airship-send-push-with-nsurlconnection)

Still I don't get anything.

I always get response as **401**. Means push is not sent.

Any idea how to send push from code itself?

Comment: @KevinDTimm : Code using same as in link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we can only send push from app only when **Push From Device** is enabled. To get this done, we have to send email to Urban Airship requesting for push for device to be enabled.

That's it!!!