# Push notification from website AND/ OR iOS device to iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsf, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have made an iPad application where I want to send push notification. For push, I am using [Urban Airship](http://www.urbanairship.com).

For adding data into database, it is done two one. One from website (technology used is JSF 2.0) and second from iPad itself.

For this I have asked Urban team to activate push from device also however I am not getting what all code I will need to write so that I can send push from website when data is added through website and from ipad when data is added from ipad.

For iPad, I was trying to use the code mentioned at below link, however I am not getting any push.

[Urban Airship - Send Push with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592762/urban-airship-send-push-with-nsurlconnection)

### OR

Is it that, push from device works only for Production mode only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below link helped me... Used PHP for the same.

http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/library.html?highlight=php

Answer (score 0):

Please find the link of my question which i have asked before [here](http://steaminghotcocoa.thecodemonsters.com/2012/08/12/integrating-remote-push-notifications-with-urban-airship-pt-2/)

I have also implemented the UrbanAirship in my project the link [here](http://steaminghotcocoa.thecodemonsters.com/2012/08/12/integrating-remote-push-notifications-with-urban-airship-pt-2/) is useful to implement this

Comment: Sir, I know this... but I want how can i send from iPad to Ipad when data is added... using this I can send push from urban website... i dnt want manually send push...

Comment: Sorry to say but as was my requirement the data was sent manually so i didn't tried on this. I will search it and tell you if possible